# Формирование словаря из списков

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Имеется два списка.

Первый:

```
key = ['load.scenarios.attempts', 'load.scenarios.succeeds', 
       'load.scenarios.fails', 'load.scenarios.aborts',
       'load.scenarios.attempts_ps', 'load.scenarios.succeeds_ps', 
       'load.scenarios.fails_ps', 'load.scenarios.aborts_ps']
```

Второй:

```
val = ['Total', 'Per Second']
```

Нужно создать словарь из них такого вида:

```
{'load.scenarios.attempts' : 'Total', 
  ...,
 'load.scenarios.attempts_ps' : 'Per Second'}


counters = {}
for k, v in zip(key, val):
    counters[k] = v
print(counters)
```

Но цикл заканчивается, когда заканчиваются значения `v`.
Но главная проблема, что бы расставить именно в указанном порядке.

Что бы "Total" относилось только к 'load.scenarios.attempts' таким значениям.

А "Per Second" только там, где есть 'load.scenarios.attempts_ps' (_ps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Через составление нового словаря:

```
items = [
    'load.scenarios.attempts', 'load.scenarios.succeeds',
    'load.scenarios.fails', 'load.scenarios.aborts',
    'load.scenarios.attempts_ps', 'load.scenarios.succeeds_ps',
    'load.scenarios.fails_ps', 'load.scenarios.aborts_ps'
]

item_by_value = {x: 'Per Second' if x.endswith('_ps') else 'Total' for x in items}
print(item_by_value)
```

Результат:

```
{
    'load.scenarios.attempts_ps': 'Per Second', 
    'load.scenarios.fails_ps': 'Per Second', 
    'load.scenarios.attempts': 'Total', 
    'load.scenarios.fails': 'Total', 
    'load.scenarios.succeeds': 'Total', 
    'load.scenarios.aborts_ps': 'Per Second', 
    'load.scenarios.aborts': 'Total', 
    'load.scenarios.succeeds_ps': 'Per Second'
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял!

Comment: @AndreySindeev, тогда отметься ответ как правильный,чтобы вопрос без ответа не висел

Answer (score 1):

```
key = ['load.scenarios.attempts', 'load.scenarios.succeeds',
   'load.scenarios.fails', 'load.scenarios.aborts',
   'load.scenarios.attempts_ps', 'load.scenarios.succeeds_ps',
   'load.scenarios.fails_ps', 'load.scenarios.aborts_ps']

res = {k: {'_ps': 'Per Second'}.get(k[-3:], 'Total') for k in key}

# {'load.scenarios.attempts': 'Total', 'load.scenarios.succeeds': 'Total', 'load.scenarios.fails': 'Total', 'load.scenarios.aborts': 'Total', 'load.scenarios.attempts_ps': 'Per Second', 'load.scenarios.succeeds_ps': 'Per Second', 'load.scenarios.fails_ps': 'Per Second', 'load.scenarios.aborts_ps': 'Per Second'}
```